# rules of logic for logical equivalence problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Use rules of logic to prove that

$ (P   \land $ Q) $\lor $ ($\neg P \land \neg Q)$

is not a tautology.

**I don't understand the first step** to get the process going on this problem. So if someone could show me what is the first step to proving it's **not a tautology**

Comment: I understand how to prove this with a truth table...

Comment: OK, then any line in the table with a false value is a counterexample.  All you have to say is something like, "The statement is false when $P$ is true and $Q$ is false," or whatever it happens to be.

Comment: If you understand how to prove it is not a tautology by a truth-table, and that's not enough, what else *are* you looking for?

Comment: The rules of logic (like identity laws, distributive laws, absorption laws) in a sequence of steps to prove that it is not a tautology. @PeterSmith

Comment: If something is not a tautology then it is not provable, i.e. it lacks a formal proof. In some cases this is due to the fact that its negation is a tautology, and thus you can find a proof of that, but usually neither the statement nor its negation will be a tautology. You could do a meta-logical induction over derivations to show that no proof exists. That would be complicated. Alternatively, you could use the fact that a substitution instance of a tautology is a tautology, and in this case prove the negation of a substitution instance is a tautology, e.g. substitute $P$ for $Q$.

Comment: Thank you @DerekElkins This really helped

Comment: Er, that should have been substitute $\neg P$ for $Q$.